# Pythonic recipe to get more flexible function currying

Tags: python, currying, functools

Builtin python offers `functools.partial` for currying, but alone it's quite limited.
My guess is that there's other builtins around whose combination with `partial` would overcome these limitations. What are they?

A few examples.

I can do this:

```py
asdf_is_instance_of = partial(isinstance, 'asdf')
assert asdf_is_instance_of(str)
```

but I can't do this (arguably more frequently useful thing to have):

```py
isinstance_of_str = partial(isinstance, class_or_tuple=str)
isinstance_of_str('asdf')
```

because `isinstance() takes no keyword arguments`.

This is one type of limitation: Having no way to circumvent parameter kind limitations directly with `partial`. For this case one could do:

```py
def my_isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple):  # just to get rid of position only parameter kinds
    return isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple)

isinstance_of_str = partial(my_isinstance, class_or_tuple=str)
assert isinstance_of_str('asdf')  # now it works
```

There's another frequent limitation: Parameter order.
One could write a `partial_ext` that would take take care of both parameter kind and order. This currying function would be such that

```py
def foo(x,y,z):
    return x + y * z

xz_foo_with_y_equal_228 = partial_ext(foo, y=228)
```

be equivalent to

```py
def xz_foo_with_y_equal_228(x, y, z):
    return foo(x, y=228, z)
```

There seems to be no such currying builtin in python, so my guess is there's some kind recipe involving other builtins that takes care of it.

Anyone know that secret?

Comment: For the second example, `partial` works well: `partial(foo, y=228)`. The key to the failure of the first example is that `isinstance` only accepts positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not a functional programming language; it is a multi-paradigm language which has some support for some limited functional programming techniques. If you want to do partial application with the *second* positional argument of a function, I doubt there is anything in the standard library which supports that "out of the box". You could write your own helper function like this:

```py
def partial_second(f, y):
    def partial_f(x, *vargs, **kwargs):
        return f(x, y, *vargs, **kwargs)
    return partial_f

is_string = partial_second(isinstance, str)
```

But I would only suggest doing this if you frequently have to do this kind of currying, and in that case you probably aren't writing idiomatic Python anyway. According to the [Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python), "explicit is better than implicit" and "simple is better than complex", so instead of currying, you could just write like this instead of using partial application:

```py
def is_string(x):
    return isinstance(x, str)
```

Comment: I'd like to not get into philosophical disagreements about programming languages or interpretations of the Zen guidelines. I would like to mention (for the crypto-nerds reading this) that I expected this sort of answer and included an easter egg for that. The `y=228` was for the SHA-256 hash `1fe01fa6c79b3bbfffa48732fe3215092abd7996fd4a8d290e2ed7119176f228` of "just use function definitions" (try it out [here](https://xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator)).

Comment: Indeed though, @kaya3, I am painfully discovering that functional support is weak in python.

Comment: I don't think we have a philosophical disagreement; I only mention it to explain why what you're looking for wouldn't be found in the standard library.